# Javascript autocomplete xml get plus attribute

Tags: jquery, xml, autocomplete

I am trying to use a javascript for an autocomplete.
I have seen online some examples, but I don't find something that does to my case.
I would want to effect two functions together, her before autocomplete the second to pass another value to another input.
I have a xml with various attributes.

```
<ROOT>
<ROW COMCOD="01344" COMLIB="SAINT-DENIS-LES-BOURG" CODPOS="01000" IDCOMM="1" ETRANG="N" COLMEE="N" CSAGES="0104P01" FUSION="N"/>
<ROW COMCOD="01914" COMLIB="BROU" CODPOS="01000" IDCOMM="2" ETRANG="N" COLMEE="O" CSAGES="" FUSION="N"/>
<ROW COMCOD="01053" COMLIB="BOURG-EN-BRESSE" CODPOS="01000" IDCOMM="3" ETRANG="N" COLMEE="N" CSAGES="0104P01" FUSION="N"/>
<ROW COMCOD="01053" COMLIB="BOURG EN BRESSE CEDEX" CODPOS="01001" IDCOMM="4" ETRANG="N" COLMEE="N" CSAGES="0104P01" FUSION="N"/>
<ROW COMCOD="01183" COMLIB="GUEREINS" CODPOS="01090" IDCOMM="5" ETRANG="N" COLMEE="N" CSAGES="0104P03" FUSION="N"/>
<ROW COMCOD="01225" COMLIB="LURCY" CODPOS="01090" IDCOMM="6" ETRANG="N" COLMEE="N" CSAGES="0104P03" FUSION="N"/>
```

When use autocomplite I want to take the value COMLIB and to fill the input of the consumer.
I would also want however to pass the value CODPOS to another input.
Am I following this example, that correctly makes me use autocomplite but I doesn't know how to also take the CODPOST and to insert it in

[I'm trying this example](http://johnstonianera.com/jquery-autocomplete-xml/)

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
 var myArr = [];

 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "myxml.xml", // change to full path of file on server
   dataType: "xml",
   success: parseXml,
   complete: setupAC,
   failure: function(data) {
     alert("XML File could not be found");
   }
 });

 function parseXml(xml)
 {
   //find every query value

   $(xml).find("ROW").each(function()
   {

      myArr.push($(this).attr("COMLIB"));

   });
 }

 function setupAC() {
   $("input#searchBox").autocomplete({
   source: myArr,
   minLength: 3,
   select: function(event, ui) {


    $("input#searchBox").val(ui.item.value);    



   }
  });
 }
});


<form name="search_form" id="searchForm" method="GET" action="search_results.html">
<label for="searchBox">Keyword Search</label>
<input type="text" id="searchBox" name="searchString" />
<input type="text" id="CODPOS" name="CODPOS" />

<button name="searchKeyword" id="searchKeyword">Sumbit</button>
</form>
```

You have some suggestion or some links to give me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function parseXml(xml)
  {
    //find every query value

    $(xml).find("ROW").each(function()
    {
     COMLIB = $(this).attr('COMLIB');
      CODPOS = $(this).attr('CODPOS');
      myArr.push({'value':COMLIB",'CODPOS':CODPOS});


    });
  }





   $("input#searchBox").autocomplete({

    source: myArr,
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
     event.preventDefault();

    $("input#searchBox").val(ui.item.value);
    $("input#CODPOS").val(ui.item.CODPOS);  



    }
   });
```